# How do I use Capybara to test that a form element is disabled when using jQuery's prop method?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, testunit

In my Rails 3 app, I've been using jQuery's attr() method to do things like this:

```
$('#application_dust_type_id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I would use Test/Unit, capybara and capybara-webkit to test this with:

```
assert page.has_selector? 'select[id=application_dust_type_id][disabled=disabled]'
```

Now, I'm trying to switch to using the prop method, as jQuery recommends:

```
$('#application_dust_type_id').prop('disabled', true)
```

But now the above assertion fails, even though the javascript still works the same in the browser.

How can I make an assertion based on an element's property (instead of an attribute) using capybara?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try just checking for the existance of a `disabled` attribute as that is all that is really required to disable an input:

```
assert page.has_selector? 'select[id=application_dust_type_id][disabled]'
```

Note that the value of a `disabled` attribute is moot. You could set `disabled="false"` or `disabled="foobar"` and the element would be rendered as disabled.